# Need assistance with escapes in my groovy command

Tags: sed, jenkins-groovy

I need to replace a version string in a file. My search pattern is regex
and my replacement is a variable.

```
String search = "\\d+.\\d+.\\d+-.\\d+"
String replace = "1.0.0-${BUILD_ID}"
MyFile = "foo"
sh ("""
     sed -i -r "s/($search/$replace/g)" $MyFile
""")
```

The result I am getting

```
+ sed -i -r s/(\d+.\d+.\d+-.\d+/1.0.0-25/g) foo
sed: bad option in substitution expression
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my code. If I remove parenthesis (), the string replacement works as a charm.